# WPF - binding to an explicitly implemented interface property from code behind/attached behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to set up a binding to an explicitly implemented interface property from code-behind.  The reason for the code-behind binding is that the path to the bound property can only be determined at run-time.

In the XAML, it is possible to bind thusly (example in MainWindow.xaml):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding (local:IViewModel.Property)}"/>
```

and in fact, binding in the code behind works in a similar way (from MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
var binding = new Binding("(local:IViewModel.Property)");
```

since WPF is able to pick up the namespace mapping.

My question is, how do I form a binding like this when the namespace mapping is not present (for example, in an attached behaviour)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would specify a full `PropertyPath`:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(IViewModel).GetProperty("Property");
var propertyPath = new PropertyPath("(0)", propertyInfo);
var binding = new Binding
{
    Path = propertyPath
};
```

For details on the syntax passed to `PropertyPath` above, see [`PropertyPath.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.path.aspx).

Comment: +1. Could you perhaps post a link to a syntax reference for this special kind of indexing. I haven't seen it before and can't find it in the [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) MSDN article. Always thought it had to use `[]`.