# INotifyPropertyChanged with Properties that have the same name

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I'm working on a system to represent data. In it we use a templetized interface that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public interface IScalar<T> : ISignal, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    void Check(T value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Formats the specified value based on the item's formatting
    /// characteristics. Will throw an exception if the specified value
    /// could not be properly converted to the underlying type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to format.</param>
    /// <returns>Formatted value.</returns>
    string Format(T value);

    T Value { get; set; }
    string Units { get; set; }
}
```

We end having a class that implements `IScalar<double>` and `IScalar<string>`. Is there a way to make sure the correct PropertyChanged event is fired? It uses a string representation of the property name. And since I have two properties with the same name I can't guarantee the right event will be fired. We are looking to have a grid in WPF bind to a list of IScalar

Comment: How is it implemented?

Comment: Can you just bind to the `IScalar<double>` and convert to strings using that value converter whatever thingy that WPF has at bind time?

Comment: Are you sure there is a *right* and a *wrong* event to be fired here? As `INotifyPropertyChanged` is somewhat simplistic, I'd presume that if you fire the `PropertyChanged` event for property name `Value`, system classes will generally assume that both properties have changed. Now, if you actually need to know which one of the properties was changed, that might prove really tricky with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Not all of the things that I'll be binding to will be IScalar<double>, but they will all be IScalar<string>

Comment: it will trigger an update for both properties since it can't distinguish them. All you get is the name. what's more interesting however is how you can bind to two properties of the same name. that sounds like a construct which should not even be possible

Comment: Basically I'll need to change the `IScalar<double>` value and this will cause a change in `IScalar<string>` value. When i set up a grid that binds to a `List<IScalar<string>>` and then manually change `IScalar<double>.Value` on one of those the `PropertyChanged` event is fired only once. The grid does change to represent the new `IScalar<string>.Value`. This is fine for now, but in the future we may not want this to function this way. Is there a way to update the `IScalar<double>.Value` and not cause the grid to recheck its `IScalar<string>.Value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from Scott's proper answer, you may also want to get away from calling the PropertyChanged Method by passing in strings. Here's how you do that:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

INPC using member/method name is now supported in the attribute class CallerMemberName found in the System.runtime.compilerservices assembly.

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

ADVANTAGES: 
  It allows you to easily establish a base class once and for all that handles all notifications based only on the method name. The setter methods merely have this line of code:

```
OnPropertyChanged();
```

Comment: Does doing this binding through WPF automatically handle different properties with the same name? For example, if I change the `IScalar<double>.Value` will the event still be fired and ignored by the grid because it is looking at `IScalar<string>`?

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft's documentation on what INOTIFYPROPERTYCHANGED actual does internally is poor at best.  However, we do know that two properties are allowed with the same name if their types differ.  I'm believe that you will be ok because the type would be a part of any fully qualified property name.  If we look at dependency properties we cannot define them without a type parameter.  Best for you would be to experiment and see if you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two properties with the same name on your datacontext.
If you did, you would have a compile error reflecting ambiguity.

Remember that your **source** is your datacontext.

In addition, the databinding system relies on both **source** and **path** in order to perform databinding.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, as this was not asked for, and I'm not even entirely convinced it is true if the binding is created in code-behind. In fact, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854466/wpf-binding-to-an-explicitly-implemented-interface-property-from-code-behind-a) suggests it is possible.

Comment: How can you have two property names that are identical on a class regardless of if it's a code-behind or view-model? At the end of the day, it's still a class that serves as your source (aka: DataContext).

Answer (score 1):

You can't implicitly implement an generic interface with two different type parameters. You have to make at least one explicit. Here you see a sample implementation for your class. As you can see you can bind to `StringValue` and `DoubleValue`:

```
public class Both : IScalar<string>, IScalar<double>
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    string IScalar<string>.Value
    {
        get
        {
            return StringValue;
        }
        set
        {
            this.StringValue = value;
        }
    }

    public double DoubleValue { get; set; }

    double IScalar<double>.Value
    {
        get
        {
            return DoubleValue;
        }
        set
        {
            DoubleValue = value;
        }
    }

    // other methods and properties left out
}
```

When you need to raise `PropertyChanged`, you can raise that event for either `StringValue` or `DoubleValue`.

Comment: "When you need to raise PropertyChanged, you can raise that event for either StringValue or DoubleValue." - Wasn't the question precisely *how* to do that for *either* the one *or* the other?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I guess OP was worried since there were two `Value`s. But there is none in my code.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to bind against DoubleValue and StringValue, the item that would be bound would be a list of `IScalar<string>`

Comment: Then you should be able to bind to value, since that is the explicit property name.