# WPF Binding to a nested property of an attached property by code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

I have to create a Binding to read the value of a property of an object that is the value of an attached property.

In XAML I can it this way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(myns:MyDependencyObject.MyAttachedProperty).NestedProperty, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

How can I do that in C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that via this approach:

```
var path = new PropertyPath("(0).NestedProperty", MyDependencyObject.MyAttachedProperty);
var binding = new Binding() { Path = path, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

The constructor used for PropertyPath is the following:

```
public PropertyPath(string path, params object[] pathParameters)
```

Please note that `"(0)"` is similar to the `string.Format` syntax, where `(0)` corresponds to the first parameter in the `pathParameters` params list.

The Microsoft's docs are not so clear about that.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854657/1136211